# What the width and height ViewGroup atonCreateViewHolder , when call parent,width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7M1g.png)
I dont understand parent,width here wikk it be width of RecyclerView or screen  or an item (1 viewHolder) is there anyone explain it  to me Thanks

I Tried and it seem to be width of RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateViewHolder()` creates a structure that hold the view used by a single item in the *RecyclerView*. That view will be a child of the parent and, in the code you posted, parent is the *RecyclerView*, so `parent.width` is the width of the *RecyclerView*.

The *RecyclerView's* width in comparison to the screen width depends on how the *RecyclerView* is defined.

Comment: I just also search RecyclerView is ViewGroup -> I think it is the width of recyclerView .thank you for helping me understand better